# Converting a JPG to BMP with exact specs

Tags: image, imagemagick, jpeg, image-manipulation, bmp

I'm trying to alter the displayed boot splash of an AMLogic device (using this tool: https://github.com/steeve/aml-imgpack). I have a JPG which I convert to BMP, as the device needs (let's say https://unsplash.com/photos/SnXIF8_2oPw) but the colors are completely wrong, the image is broken in "lines" and some parts from left are to the right (a bit like repeating the image, but not completely).

The original image, have the following attributes:

```
$ magick identify -verbose ../original/bootup.bmp
Image:
  Filename: ../original/bootup.bmp
  Format: BMP (Microsoft Windows bitmap image)
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 1920x1080+0+0
  Resolution: 28.34x28.34
  Print size: 67.7488x38.1087
  Units: PixelsPerCentimeter
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Type: TrueColor
  Base type: Undefined
  Endianness: Undefined
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    Red: 8-bit
    Green: 8-bit
    Blue: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 2073600
    Red:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 4.64305 (0.018208)
      standard deviation: 31.5717 (0.12381)
      kurtosis: 47.4739
      skewness: 6.93758
      entropy: 0.0513943
    Green:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 3.77976 (0.0148226)
      standard deviation: 26.4192 (0.103605)
      kurtosis: 55.8096
      skewness: 7.40689
      entropy: 0.0502694
    Blue:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 239 (0.937255)
      mean: 1.81429 (0.00711485)
      standard deviation: 13.2764 (0.0520643)
      kurtosis: 84.5432
      skewness: 8.63456
      entropy: 0.0528362
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 3.41236 (0.0133818)
      standard deviation: 23.7558 (0.0931598)
      kurtosis: 67.5353
      skewness: 8.07788
      entropy: 0.0515
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0,0)
    green primary: (0,0)
    blue primary: (0,0)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Matte color: grey74
  Background color: white
  Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
  Transparent color: none
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 1920x1080+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: Undefined
  Orientation: Undefined
  Convex hull: 931,391 932,391 1111,432 1223,484 1230,488 1247,544 1247,549 1244,551 1015,623 919,623 704,551 688,471 688,448 696,432 931,391
  Minimum bounding box: 1247,391 1247,623 688,623 688,391
  Properties:
    date:create: 2020-10-31T22:40:38+00:00
    date:modify: 2020-10-31T22:40:38+00:00
    minimum-bounding-box:_p: 931,391
    minimum-bounding-box:_q: 932,391
    minimum-bounding-box:_v: 1015,623
    minimum-bounding-box:angle: 0
    minimum-bounding-box:area: 129688
    minimum-bounding-box:height: 559
    minimum-bounding-box:unrotate: -0
    minimum-bounding-box:width: 232
    signature: 31151e021e5d4cdde8d345165d8eb9cd6489f307272c8ca455d038002885d405
  Artifacts:
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 3.95515MiB
  Number pixels: 2073600
  Pixels per second: 79.4977MP
  User time: 0.020u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.026
  Version: ImageMagick 7.0.10-30 Q16 x86_64 2020-09-20 https://imagemagick.org
```

I tried to convert using:

```sh
$ mogrify -format bmp ../new_bootup.jpg
$ mogrify -format bmp -type TrueColor ../new_bootup.jpg
$ mogrify -format bmp -define bmp:subtype=RGB565 ../new_bootup.jpg
```

but the image did not show correctly. The question is: which flags should I use (or which tool should I use) to achieve as close relpication of the original attributes as possible?

Comment: Which is your input image from the link? Perhaps post it or a link to it. Is the input color or grayscale? Is the input JPG in CMYK or RGB? If in CMYK, that could be the issue. What is your IM version and platform? Have you tried using convert rather than mogrify. `convert image.jpg img.bmp` or  for output you could try BMP3:img.bmp or BMP2:img.bmp. Your IM may be corrupt. Try installing again if the above does not help. Also be sure you have plenty of room in your temp directory.

Comment: If it is the black/white image, I can convert that just fine using IM 6.9.11.34 or IM 7.0.10.34 on Mac OSX Sierra. I can view it fine with several tools including IM display. I see no stripes or offsets. `convert photo-1568876694728-451bbf694b83.jpeg photo-1568876694728-451bbf694b83.bmp`.  So I suspect an issue with your version or installation of IM.